# how to create calenderView as pop up window on edittext in android studio?

Tags: android

hello I want to show calender view as pop up to user so user can put date and it will appear on edit text. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in your activity:

```
public static class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        month = month + 1;
        if (month < 10 && day < 10) {
            txt_dob.setText(year + "-" + "0" + month + "-" + "0" + day);
        } else {
            txt_dob.setText(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
        }
    }
}
```

Code for onclick:

```
txt_dob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DateDialog();
            newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "datePicker");
        }
    });
```

It will show you pop-up and selected date is set on Textview.

Comment: DateDialog(); and getActivity() method not working means its showing cannot resolve method getActivity() and DateDialog();

Comment: Replace getActivity() to "YOUR ACTIVITY NAME.this"

Comment: for Date Dialog

Comment: For dialog import use this - import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;